# What is a client in SAP system?

Tags: abap, netweaver

Can someone please explain me what a client in a SAP NetWeaver system using the ABAP stack is and how does it create logical separations within the same installation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One SAP system can be used for several independent companies (or subsidiaries of a company). The client is used to separate the data of these companies. Most database tables in an SAP system therefore have the client is a key. This is used e.g. for transactional data, master data and client dependent customizing data. Nevertheless there is also customizing that is valid across all clients (so called cross client customizing.)

In a nutshell: Client is a key field in most database tables to separate data of multiple companies using the same SAP system. Each company has its own client number.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That explains it. If client number is used as a field in DB tables, it will create a logical separation.

Comment: yup. The `client` field, if present, is always the first field in a table, it's called `MANDT` and is of type `MANDT` - character of length 3.

Comment: @vlad-ardelean: The field does *not* have to be called `MANDT` and it might be of any data type (data element) that refers to the data type `CLNT`.

Comment: Note that you can check the client in your ABAP code with system field `SY-MANDT`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Christian Trebing's answer, there are some more important points to note.

1. A users logs into a client. Every client has separate set users and authentication.
2. Generally all the database operation on a table having "client" field, the code does not need to specify the client. It is already taken care by the system.

Most of the standard processes, (business transactions/ external communication etc) already are set up specific to the client and execute that way.